# find two closest values in numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

i have a numpy ndarray which looks like this

```
np.array(
[[40.26164428, 63.50590524, 58.30951895],
 [50.99019514, 69.0651866 , 60.44005295],
 [20.24845673, 14.31782106, 58.52349955],
 [54.58937626, 53.03772242, 21.09502311],
 [56.75385449, 57.5847202 ,  1.41421356]])
```

(NOTE: the arrays i generate are always in different shapes ( the shape of this array is (5, 3) but it can be (2, 2) (4, 1)... ),
so this isn't a 3D coordinates array, it just generated like that)

What i need is to find the two closest values of the generated array and return their indices, in this case the values are `58.30951895` and `58.52349955`, which should return the coordinates `[0, 2] and [2, 2]`

I've tried to use cKDtree but this isn't a coordinate array so that doesn't work in this case, how should i do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to be embarrassed when someone points out a one-liner, but here's a way to do it.

I flatten the array, then sort it, then find the deltas between each element.  Find the minimum delta.  Now, from the sorted array, I know the values of the two closest elements.  `argwhere` then gives me the coordinates.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array(
[[40.26164428, 63.50590524, 58.30951895],
 [50.99019514, 69.0651866 , 60.44005295],
 [20.24845673, 14.31782106, 58.52349955],
 [54.58937626, 53.03772242, 21.09502311],
 [56.75385449, 57.5847202 ,  1.41421356]])


order = np.sort(data.reshape(-1))
delta = np.diff(order)
am = np.argmin(delta)
print( np.argwhere(data == order[am]))
print( np.argwhere(data == order[am+1]))
```

Output:

```
C:\tmp>python x.py
[[0 2]]
[[2 2]]
```

Comment: you have extra pair of [] at the end and that is why you get 3 numbers instead of 2, and turn out that numpy have function for the delta part so you can change that for it too: `np.diff(order)`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly their position in the array is irrelevant, so in that case is simple, put the numbers in a list in a way that it remember their original position, then sorted it and find the lowest difference between two consecutive elements

```
>>> import itertools
>>> def pairwise(iterable):
        a,b = itertools.tee(iterable)
        next(b,None)
        return zip(a,b)

>>> data=[[40.26164428, 63.50590524, 58.30951895],
 [50.99019514, 69.0651866,  60.44005295],
 [20.24845673, 14.31782106, 58.52349955],
 [54.58937626, 53.03772242, 21.09502311],
 [56.75385449, 57.5847202,   1.41421356]]
>>> linear=[ (value,x,y) for x,row in enumerate(data) for y,value in enumerate(row)]
>>> linear.sort(key=lambda x:x[0])
>>> min(pairwise(linear),key=lambda pair: abs(pair[0][0]-pair[1][0]))
((58.30951895, 0, 2), (58.52349955, 2, 2))
>>>
```